# Order of library search path entries

Tags: objective-c, cordova, xcode6, static-libraries, xcodebuild

I have created a Cordova project.

For iOS Cordova generates two XCode projects: an **application project**, and *inside the application project* a **CordovaLib project** is created.

To use maven I am trying to substitute the CordovaLib project with a static library.

Deleted the CordovaLib project, and added four versions of libCordovaLib.a as linked libraries: 
1. debug iphoneOS
2. debug iphoneSimulator
3. release iphoneOS
4. release iphoneSimulator

Extended the header search path as needed, and extended the library search path also:

```
$(inherited)
target/libs/Debug-iphoneos/...path.../CordovaLib 
target/libs/Debug-iphonesimulator/...path.../CordovaLib
. (Note that first is iphoneos, than comes iphonesimulator).
```

*XCode now builds the application successfully for real test device, but fails to build for emulator (linker errors).* There is a **warning** before the errors:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   target/libs/Debug-iphoneos/...path.../CordovaLib/libCordovaLib.a,
>   missing required architecture i386 in file
>   target/libs/Debug-iphoneos/...path.../CordovaLib/libCordovaLib.a (3
>   slices)

Now comes the interesting part:

If I switch the order of library search path entries, XCode builds successfully for emulator, but fails to build for real test device, producing a similar **warning**:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   target/libs/Debug-iphonesimulator/...path.../CordovaLib/libCordovaLib.a,
>   missing required architecture arm64 in file
>   target/libs/Debug-iphonesimulator/...path.../CordovaLib/libCordovaLib.a
>   (2 slices)

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? Is there any build variable I should use in library search path to match always the needed one device/emulator? I googled but found no similar things.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Somebody enlightened me:

The solution is : Include `BUILD_STYLE` and `PLATFORM_NAME` build setting variables.